# Detect if a @keyframes rule exists without iterating all stylesheets?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Is there a way to detect whether a CSS3 animation with a specific name exists,  *without* iterating through all CSS rules?

Can be a solution using a JS library, or plain JS. Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

1. Create a dummy element.
2. Bind an [`animationstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/animationstart) event to this dummy element.
3. Set the `.style.animationName` (with appropriate vendor-prefix).
4. Insert the element in the document and see whether the event is triggered within a few ms.

If the event is not triggered, assume that the animation does not exist. Don't forget to clean up the element (i.e. remove it from the DOM).

By design, this method is asynchronous. It is more reliable than iterating through all style sheets though, because the latter method fails if an animation is declared in a style sheet from a different origin.

## Example

```
function animationExists(animationName, callback) {
    var dummy = document.createElement('dummy');
    var done = function(result) {
        if (dummy.parentNode) {
            dummy.parentNode.removeChild(dummy);
            callback(result);
        }
    };
    var onanimstart = function() {
        done(true);
    };
    // Animations won't be triggered until the tab is visible:
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        done(false);
    });
    if (typeof dummy.style.animationName != 'undefined') {
        dummy.style.animationName = animationName;
        dummy.style.animationDuration = '0.001s';
        dummy.addEventListener('animationstart', onanimstart);
    } else {
        dummy.style.webkitAnimationName = animationName;
        dummy.style.webkitAnimationDuration = '0.001s';
        dummy.addEventListener('webkitAnimationStart', onanimstart);
    }
    (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(dummy);
}
```

The previous function correctly detects whether an animation exists in:

- Firefox 16+ (if you wish to support FF 5 - 15, include a `moz`-prefixed branch).
- Chrome 10+
- Opera 12.1+
- Safari 6.0 (if you want to support Safari 4 - 5.1, add a polyfill for requestAnimationFrame)
- IE 10+

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7mjSd/ (shows two alert boxes).

Comment: Excellent, I had a feeling there might be a solution in this style :)